# c# Could not find file or assembly cefsharp.core.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cefsharp

This is a known issue with Cefsharp when I open the application I get this error. People have so many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365731/cefsharp-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-core-dll-or-one-of-its-dep) to this but none of them work for me until I open vs installer and install 2 component in the system that I am going to run my application. these Items are:

1. Just in Time Debuger
2. Performance profiler

Do you know what causes this problem? and I have to open vs installer and install these items in every computer?

Comment: Maybe you can share some links which descripes the problems and the function that did not work for you.

Comment: Can you check which platform version (x86 or x64) are you referring to and if your project is targeting that platform.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I have tested x86 ,x64 any cpu prefer 32 bit ..all case scenarios

Comment: Make sure you read the `Post Installation` notes https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/71/NuGet/Readme.txt#L7

Comment: @amaitland Thanks problem solved after installing c++ 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved after installing c++ 2015. It turned out that each version of Cefsharp requires different version of  c++ redistributable. I had 2017 and 2013 not the 2015