# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. Only on some pcs

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have an application using `CefSharp` with winforms, and C# in visual studio.
I've tested it on the pc I used to create it and it worked fine, even multiple pcs in best buy / walmart (don't ask).

However, when I went to actually use my program on my old computer, it failed to run with the error

> Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of
> its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. File name:
> 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' The file "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" is
> there in that same directory. The program will run but will not run
> with cefsharp.

Is this issue with just the computer its running on or is it an issue with my application? If so, for either of them how may I fix it?

All source code for this specific project at https://github.com/bytespacegames/Bullb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CefSharp - Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365731/cefsharp-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-core-dll-or-one-of-its-dep)

Comment: @viveknuna I don't believe so, even though the file names are similar, mine is .Core.Runtime, which I found not much else about, and most of those solutions do not work for me.

Comment: Do you have Visual C++ 2019 installed? Missing the correct VC++ version is the most common cause of problems running on non dev machines. CefSharp.Core.dll was renamed to CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll some time ago

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/96/NuGet/Readme.txt#L16

Comment: @amaitland is there any way I can have each machine not manually install anything? I want them to only have to download what's included with my app. And I also have a file CefSharp.Core.dll so I assumed they were different.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Including_vcredist

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3407#issuecomment-790225156 for an example build target for VS2019. This will only copy the VC++ runtime, not the universal CRT. Universal CRT is included as part of win 10/11. Read links in FAQ entry I linked above for more details.